# Putting two JavaScripts together that duplicate inputs

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me put these two JavaScripts together?

Console is sending me an error from these two inline files.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var 
    first = document.getElementById('jform_username'),
    second = document.getElementById('jform_email1'),
    third = document.getElementById('jform_email2');

    first.onkeyup = function () {
      second.value = first.value;
      third.value = first.value;
    };     
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var 
    firstp = document.getElementById('jform_password1'),
    secondp = document.getElementById('jform_password2');

    firstp.onkeyup = function () {
      secondp.value = firstp.value;
    };     
    </script>
```

If you can also provide an explanation of why these two can create errors that would be great.

I think it has something to do with the function but I don't know.

Here is a picture of the actual problem.

[image]

This is the new problem based on @Shubham Singla solution

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide us the error message?

Comment: The first step is to remove " </script> <script type="text/javascript">" and then report the error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change keyup to firstp.addEventListener("keyup",function()...

## code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var 
first = document.getElementById('jform_username'),
second = document.getElementById('jform_email1'),
third = document.getElementById('jform_email2');

first.addEventListener("keyup",function () {
  second.value = first.value;
  third.value = first.value;
});     

var 
firstp = document.getElementById('jform_password1'),
secondp = document.getElementById('jform_password2');

firstp.addEventListener("keyup",function () {
  secondp.value = firstp.value;
});   
});  
</script>
```

This was in additio to other answer. so updated the code with it.

Comment: Can you post how the final code should look? I will appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: After using your code now it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' " - Just posted the image on my edits

Comment: can you add your html where these fields are defined

Comment: i can't see any element with id jform_username. Can you point to it

Comment: Yes I just realize that, please go to sign up page

Comment: Eliminate CSS to see all input fields

Comment: If you are trying to get jform_username in jform_email1 and jform_email2 as user types and same for password. its working fine. Else please clarify what you are asking

Comment: I know they work, I was just trying to eliminate the message that it shows on the picture

Comment: the error message that says  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149886/discussion-between-shubham-singla-and-lupoll88).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to `.getElementById` before the document is "ready".

Use below code to wait for document to be "ready" before you can get element.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //content here
});
```

Check the snippet below :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var 
    first = document.getElementById('jform_username'),
    second = document.getElementById('jform_email1'),
    third = document.getElementById('jform_email2');

    first.onkeyup = function () {
      second.value = first.value;
      third.value = first.value;
    };     
    
    var 
    firstp = document.getElementById('jform_password1'),
    secondp = document.getElementById('jform_password2');

    firstp.onkeyup = function () {
      secondp.value = firstp.value;
    };     
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="jform_username" />
<input type="text" id="jform_email1" />
<input type="text" id="jform_email2" />
<input type="text" id="jform_password1" />
<input type="text" id="jform_password2" />
```

Comment: I changed as you suggested but this problem is showing. Please see the image inside my new edited question. It says "Uncaught TypeError cannot set property 'onkeyup' " Thanks